# Python: how to change (last) element of tuple?

Tags: python

The question is a bit misleading, because a tuple is *immutable*. What I want is:

Having a tuple `a = (1, 2, 3, 4)` get a tuple `b` that is exactly like `a` except for the last argument which is, say, twice the last element of `a`.

=> b == (1, 2, 3, 8)

Comment: If you can help it, consider using a list if you're going to be doing in-place manipulation of elements.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to use tuples in my scenario - I need to represent program versions, in the form 
`major.minor.branch.build -> (major, minor, branch, build) `
and I need to get the version of 'previous build' from a given version

Comment: You can also use the `distutils.version.StrictVersion` class for version numbers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
b = a[:-1] + (a[-1]*2,)
```

What I'm doing here is concatenation of two tuples, the first containing everything but the last element, and a new tuple containing the mutation of the final element.  The result is a new tuple containing what you want.

Note that for `+` to return a tuple, both operands must be a tuple.

Comment: How about `(a[-1] * 2,)`? The above throws a TypeError. (the trailing comma is necessary for a one-item tuple)

Answer (score 8):

I would do something like:

```
b=list(a)
b[-1]*=2
b=tuple(b)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> b = a[:-1] + (a[-1]*2, )
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> b
(1, 2, 3, 8)
```

So what happens on the second line? a[:-1] means all of a except the last element. a[-1] is the last element, and we multiply it by two. The (a[-1]*2, ) turns the result into a tuple, and the sliced tuple is concatenated with it using the + operator. The result is put in b.

You can probably fit this to your specific case.